# char16_t and char32_t types in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, visual-studio-2013

As I understand, in C++11 `char16_t` and `char32_t` are not typedefs, but new primitive data types. (please correct me if I am wrong).

I writing a library meant to be used on linux gcc and Windows Visual Studio. So I write a trait:

```
template <class T>
struct IsChar : std::false_type {
};

template <>
struct IsChar<char> : std::true_type {
};

template <>
struct IsChar<wchar_t> : std::true_type {
};

template <>
struct IsChar<char16_t> : std::true_type {
};

template <>
struct IsChar<char32_t> : std::true_type {
};
```

However, I have noticed that in VS (2013), `char16_t` and `char32_t` are just typedefs for `unsigned short` and `unsigned` in `[..]\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\yvals.h`.

So I checked and

`std::is_same<char32_t, unsigned>::value`

is `true` in VS and `false` in gcc.

So my questions are:

1. Are `char16_t` and `char32_t` new primitive types in the standard (Is VS implementation of these two types non-standard?)
2. Are these two types new primitives types in gcc, or just another typedefs (but maybe not the same typedefs as in VS)?'
3. Is VS planning on implementing these types as new primitive types in the near future?

Comment: Not only are `char16_t` and `char32_t` distinct types, but `signed char` and `unsigned char` are distinct from `char` as well. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0851febbf71772dd

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler does not yet support the `char16_t` and `char32_t` types.  Until such time that it does, we use typedefs in the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1: They are distinct types according to

> #### 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]
>
> <sup>5</sup> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.3.1). Type `wchar_t` shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its *underlying type*. Types `char16_t` and `char32_t` **denote distinct types** with the same size, signedness, and alignment as `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, respectively, in `<cstdint>`, called the underlying types.

(emphasis mine)

This means GCC is correct and VS is wrong.

For 2: GCC implements them as intended, i.e., as distinct types.

For 3: Only Microsoft can answer that question, but I think it's likely that they will implement them correctly. Compiler vendors sometimes simply use a hack as a work-around to bridge the gap until a full solution is ready.

Comment: "in" what? Header names including `<` and `>` look like tags and get stripped. :)

Comment: Interesting. What are you reading from? I see `<stdint.h>` instead of `<cstdint>` (although the meaning is the same)

Comment: @hvd n3797 and yeah, not the official standard but IMHO close enough :)